# Python for loops duplicate content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This questions might have already been asked before, but i can never understand it, because it doesn't correlate to my code. Yes i have referenced python [for loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm)

I just can't wrap my head around it

**Main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


glimit = 5


def craigslist_spider(max_pages):
    page = 100
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://orlando.craigslist.org/search/apa?s=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
        limit = glimit
        mysoup = soup.findAll('a',{'class':'result-title hdrlnk'})[:limit]
        mysoup2 = soup.findAll('time',{'class':'result-date'})[:limit]
        for link in mysoup:
            for link2 in mysoup2:
                href = "https://orlando.craigslist.org" + link.get('href')
                title = link.string
                date = link2.string
                owl = (date) + (title)
                print owl
            # get_single_item_data(href)
        page += 100


# def get_single_item_data(item_url):
#     source_code = requests.get(item_url)
#     plain_text = source_code.text
#     soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
#     limit = glimit
#     mysoup = soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'mapaddress' })[:limit]
#     for item in mysoup:
#         if item in mysoup is not None:
#             print (item.string)
#         else:
#             print("No Address")

craigslist_spider(100)
```

produces 5 times of duplicate content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer loop is running 5 times and repeating the inner loop.  These shouldn't be nested; otherwise you get the same inner link repeated multiple times.

Instead, loop over a *findall()* on `<p class="result-info">`. Within each of those paragraphs, do a single *find()* for the `"result-date"` subelement and another *find()* on the `"result-title"` element.

```
for result in soup.findAll('p', {'class': 'result-info'})[:limit]:
    link = result.find('a',{'class':'result-title hdrlnk'})
    link2 = result.find('time',{'class':'result-date'})
    href = "https://orlando.craigslist.org" + link.get('href')
    title = link.string
    date = link2.string
    owl = (date) + (title)
    print owl
    ...
```

Comment: Dude this awesome, i think understand this now. Much respect raymond